# How to get around space limitations in iOS?

Tags: ios, backup, storage

Apple seems to take out a lot of profit-margin on Memory.  I don't like to pay that much "Just to be sure".   How easy is it to get around the limitations?

I am thinking of something like wireless disks, moving stuff to/from backup locations and silently pushing recorded photos and videos to somewhere else.

I know this can easily be done for different kinds of space hogs?
(I know it can easily be done for movies)

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking if this can easily be done for different kinds of space hogs, the answer is yes.

For example you could be using iCloud to push photos, videos, etc. out in the cloud to limit the amount of space used on the device itself.

You can also purchase wireless disks, tethered disks, etc. to store files on there. They usually come with third party apps to manage the space and move files around.

Note however that you cannot keep apps anywhere but the local device if you want to be able to run them.

Comment: Ideally it should be possible to push to different (local locations), and silently delete stuff that is saved.
--
For me, podcast apps quickly fill up the space, so it could be useful if these could also be moved out locally.
----
It does seem for iOS its difficult to backup/delete/restore single apps.

Comment: You can just use iTunes to determine which apps you want on the phone and to backup them. You can delete single apps directly from the springboard on the iPhone. It's not that difficult.